# Why arrays of bytes give different numbers after converting to big int in Go and in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, go, byte

I have an array of bytes which I convert to big int and output to the console.

**In C#:**
https://dotnetfiddle.net/eNz1Lg

**In Go:**
https://play.golang.org/p/gXKoEja_8Dd

Why in result I have different numbers?

**C# result:** 29063245685294006143166067625254036131869872254473278645853807481306566623231

**Go result:** 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336

Comment: Because Go's big.Int and C#'s BigInteger use different byte representations? Why do you think they should be the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `BigInteger` has *different representation* in **C#** and **Go**. Let's provide the *same easy to operate array*

```
    {0x01, 0x02}
```

and see what's going on:

**Go**

```
var array = []byte{
    0x01, 0x02, 
}

var seed = new(big.Int).SetBytes(array)
str := seed.String()

fmt.Println(str)
```

Outcome is **258** (note, `258 == 0x01 * 256 + 0x02`)

**C#**

```
var array = new byte[]
{
    0x01, 0x02,
};

var seed = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(array);

Console.WriteLine($"{seed}");
```

Outcome is **513** (note, `513 == 0x01 + 0x02 * 256`)

So **Go** converts `byte[]` into `BigInteger` from *last to first*:

```
       array[array.Length - 1] + 
       array[array.Length - 2] * 256 +  
       array[array.Length - 3] * 256 * 256 + 
       ...
       array[0] * Pow(256, array.Length - 1)
```

When **C#** does it from *first to last*:

```
       array[0] + 
       array[1] * 256 + 
       array[2] * 256 * 256 +
       ...
       array[array.Length - 1] * Pow(256, array.Length - 1)
```

Comment: Interesting, does Go do that even on a x86/x64 architecture (little-endian), sounds almost like a bug?